# Python converting timestamp issue

Tags: python

Im trying to covert the string value with timestamp as well as timedelta.

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

frmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
start = '2020-12-01 10:10:00'
stime = datetime.strptime(start, frmt)
print(stime)
etime =  stime.timedelta(days=1)
print(stime)
print(etime)
```

but its giving the following error.

```
2020-12-01 10:10:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

Comment: Indeed, `datetime.datetime` objects don't have a `timedelta` method. You imported the `timedelta` class with `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`, so why not use that?

Comment: What do I export?  both date time and timedelta separately?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you're trying calculate `etime` as one day after `stime` do `etime = stime + timedelta(days=1)`

Comment: yes etime will be one day after time, but stime will be used as a variable

Comment: @Bhuvanesh Then the solution is to replace `etime =  stime.timedelta(days=1)` with `etime =  stime + timedelta(days=1)`.

Comment: Oh yes, it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked from the comments:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

frmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
start = '2020-12-01 10:10:00'

stime = datetime.strptime(start, frmt)
etime =  stime + timedelta(days=1)

print('stime', stime, 'etime', etime)
```